# Excel generating wrong scale for graph, plotted points disappear when corrected

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

[image: First generated graph]

[image: Second corrected values]

I'm trying to generate a graph using the values listed in the data tables above the graph; when first generated the scale of the x-axis is wrong and when corrected, the plotted points disappear. How can I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first data point is a text cell with the value `(torr)`. That causes Excel to use **categorical** data on the X axis instead of the numerical values. It numbers the data points from 1 to 10. If you move the X axis to show categories starting from 400, there is no data there.

Change the data source of the X and Y to start from the first row with numbers and the chart will plot correctly.